# Cannot substitute values after converting string to expression with Sympify()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to convert a string into an expression via Sympy like so:

```
profit = "((MaxSalesCapacity * PctStoreUtilizationRate) * AvgSaleSize) - ((TotalRevenues * AvgCostGoods) + FixedCosts)"
eqn = sympify(profit)
```

Then I test is to see if it works, this is what I get:

```
print(eqn)
−+−
```

However, when I try to replace, values, like this: `eqn.subs(TotalRevenues, 100)`, I get this error:

***NameError: name 'TotalRevenues' is not defined***

What am I doing wrong here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with any of your API calls. `TotalRevenues` - the identifier you are passing to `eqn.subs` was never defined in the Python program. You did define a symbol of that name as part of the expression you passed to `sympify`, but that does not induce the creation of a Python identifier. You need to put the name of the SymPy symbol in quotes when passing to further API calls. The full code would look like this:

```
from sympy import sympify

profit = "((MaxSalesCapacity * PctStoreUtilizationRate) * AvgSaleSize) - ((TotalRevenues * AvgCostGoods) + FixedCosts)"
eqn = sympify(profit)
print(eqn)
seqn = eqn.subs("TotalRevenues", 100)
print(seqn)
```

The output wpoiuld look like what I would expect it to look:

```
-AvgCostGoods*TotalRevenues + AvgSaleSize*MaxSalesCapacity*PctStoreUtilizationRate - FixedCosts
-100*AvgCostGoods + AvgSaleSize*MaxSalesCapacity*PctStoreUtilizationRate - FixedCosts
```

Also, note that the `subs()` method does not mutate the object for which it called, but instead, returns a new object, with the substitution applied to it. I stored this in the `seqn` variable.

Comment: Thanks Amitai. What can I do if I want to create a Python identifier?

Comment: Assignments create (or update) python identifiers. Your original code creates two - `profit` and `eqn`. You could assign `TotalRevenues = "TotalRevenues"`, and then call `eqn.subs(TotalRevenues, 100)`, but for now, this is just doing the same thing, but with extra steps.

Comment: Gotcha. Understood.